# Cuda Parallel execution

Tags: cuda

Can somebody enlighten me on this: are blocks executed in parallel/concurrently in CUDA? 
In other words if two different blocks try to write to the same global address i.e.  globalPtr[12], is there a lost update issue?

(I am asking this as I have read that the parallel execution unit in CUDA is the warp=32 threads.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, multiple blocks execute in parallel, so accesses to global memory need to be atomic if more than one thread needs to access the same address. This applies whether it's two threads within the same block or two threads in different blocks.

Comment: Thanks Paul, though two threads within the same block need to be atomic if they belong to the same warp. If not, then they do not execute in parallel, to my knowledge so far..

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can get parallel execution between multiple blocks if the CUDA device has multiple warp schedulers.

CUDA devices with compute capability 2.1 have two warp schedulers, so an instruction from two different warps (from the same block or from different blocks, doesn't matter) can execute concurrently.

CUDA devices with compute capability 3.0 have four warp schedulers, and can issue two independent instructions per warp that is ready to execute.

Note that even without concurrent execution between warps, it is advantageous to have multiple blocks available to the scheduler so that if a warp is blocked waiting for a memory operation to complete, the scheduler can switch to another warp for execution so the cores don't sit idle.

The number of warps that can be resident on a core ready for the scheduler to switch to varies by compute capability.

If you only define as many blocks as you have schedulers, you will not be able to achieve the full compute potential of your device. This is particularly true if your code has a lot of memory I/O - one way to "hide" memory latency is to make sure there are enough blocks/warps available so the scheduler(s) always have a ready warp to switch to when one of the warps goes idle waiting for a memory I/O.

Whenever you have multiple warps reading and writing the same memory address, you should use atomic I/O or take a lock, regardless of whether your current hardware can execute multiple warps concurrently. Write-after-write artifacts ("lost updates") can manifest even in task-switched single core execution.

Comment: That is very clear thanks. That made me go and read the relevant Cuda documentation to get a better understanding. I am coding a kernel that uses nested loops to update a 32*32 shared memory. I understand that if the kernel was issued with 32 threads then i could guarantee no race conditions in my shared memory. However i am issuing it with 256 threads. Is there any way that i could guarantee that no two warps will run concurrently on the same block other than using predicates such as if(threadIdx.x<n*32){..code..}_syncthreads()  ?

Comment: Well, you could pull it back to running only 32 threads per block, but on bigger CUDA iron I suspect that will create more of a performance problem than using atomic writes.